# Fourier Series Expansion of Piecewise Linear Waveforms

Tags: fourier-analysis

[Graph of Piecewise Linear Waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0ypO.png)

Find the Fourier Series Expansion.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your effort?

Comment: I'm not sure what formulae to use, my lecturer covered coefficients for square waves but piece linear waveforms aren't very well explained.